# Java timer class, to fire at a fixed time everyday

Tags: java, timer

I want to write a simple timer class that fires , and makes a method call at a fixed time of every day, while the application is running.

I dont want to use Quartz as I think its a overkill for this simple problem, what are the different approaches I can try for ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Quartz overkill? You should definitely try it, you'll get the job done in no time.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use [java.util.Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and java.util.TimerTask?

Answer (score 1):

The util.concurrent's [ScheduledExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) allows you to pretty easily schedule tasks to run on a fixed delay. The signature of the schedule method is as follows:

```
scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable command, long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit)
```

You could find the difference between the current time and the time in which you wish to have it first run. Set the difference as the value for *initialDelay*. Set the *period* to 1 and the TimeUnit *unit* to TimeUnit.DAYS. That will cause it to run every day at that time.